# XSLT Displaying a list of nodes in groups of 2

Tags: xslt

So say I have a list of nodes that look like this:

```
<node value="red">
  <list num="1">ABC</list>
  <list num="2">DEF</list>
  <list num="3">GHI</list>
</node>
<node value="blue">
  <list num="4">JKL</list>
  <list num="5">MNO</list>
</node>
...
```

Where under each node the number of `<list>` items is not always the same amount.
I want to output in groups of 2, using xslt 1.0, showing each combination of items. So something like this:

```
<node value="red">
  <list num="1">ABC</list>
  <list num="2">DEF</list>
</node>
<node value="red">
  <list num="1">ABC</list>
  <list num="3">GHI</list>
</node>
<node value="red">
  <list num="2">DEF</list>
  <list num="3">GHI</list>
</node>
<node value="blue">
  <list num="4">JKL</list>
  <list num="5">MNO</list>
</node>
...
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node">
        <xsl:for-each select="list">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::list" >
                <xsl:with-param name ="l1" select="." />
                <xsl:with-param name ="node" select=".." />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="list">
        <xsl:param name ="l1" />
        <xsl:param name ="node" />
        <node>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$node/@*" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="$l1"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </node>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
    <node value="red">
        <list num="1">ABC</list>
        <list num="2">DEF</list>
        <list num="3">GHI</list>
    </node>
    <node value="blue">
        <list num="4">JKL</list>
        <list num="5">MNO</list>
    </node>
</xml>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
    <node value="red">
        <list num="1">ABC</list>
        <list num="2">DEF</list>
    </node>
    <node value="red">
        <list num="1">ABC</list>
        <list num="3">GHI</list>
    </node>
    <node value="red">
        <list num="2">DEF</list>
        <list num="3">GHI</list>
    </node>
    <node value="blue">
        <list num="4">JKL</list>
        <list num="5">MNO</list>
    </node>
</xml>
```